# Item changing in dom-repeat not communicated to other items

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

We are building a polymer application. 
We have an **array of elements**, which are shown in a component using **dom-repeat**. Here is an example snippet:

```
//main component
<h2>List of elements</h2>
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{elements}}" as="item" indexAs="index">
    <another-component element="{{item}}" ident$="{{index}}"></another-component>
</template>
```

and

```
//sub component
<h3>{{element.name}}</h3>
<h4>{{element.person.name}}</h4>
<paper-button on-tap="_changeName">Change name!</paper-button>
```

The objects of the array have some common references. You can see them like this :

```
//main component
<script>
    var fred = {"name": "fred"};
    var tom = {"name": "tom"};

    Polymer({
        is: 'example-component',
        properties: {
            elements: {
                type: Array,
                value: [{"name": "Main1", "person": fred}, {"name": "Main2", "person": tom}, {"name": "Main3", "person": fred}],
                notify: true
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Now, in my items I want to be able to change a nested element.

In this example, I want item 3's person value to change.

But since item 3's person reference is the same as for item 1, I would also expect person 1 to change.

However, What I do experience is that item 1 is not updated.

[There is a complete example setup at this address.](https://github.com/jlengrand/polymer-array-bubble-up-example) (I could get jsfiddle to work with my dependencies properly...).

So far I have tried to look into

- listeners
- notifyPath
- observers

without success.
I also would like to avoid passing my whole array to my items.

I know it would be easily solved using a state object like Redux for example, so unfortunately this cannot be a solution here.

I have found a lot of resources in the internet on how to get data to bubble down, but not to bubble up like I am trying to do now.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

The complete code for reference :

Main component

```
<link rel="import" href="/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="/components/another-component/another-component.html">

<dom-module id="example-component">
    <template>
        <style>
            :host {
                display: block;
            }
        </style>

        <h1>Example</h1>

        <h2>List of elements</h2>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{elements}}" as="item" indexAs="index">
            <another-component element="{{item}}" ident$="{{index}}"></another-component>
        </template>

    </template>
    <script>
        var fred = {"name": "fred"};
        var tom = {"name": "tom"};

        Polymer({
            is: 'example-component',
            properties: {
                elements: {
                    type: Array,
                    value: [{"name": "Main1", "person": fred}, {"name": "Main2", "person": tom}, {"name": "Main3", "person": fred}],
                    notify: true
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Sub component

```
<dom-module id="another-component">
    <template>
        <style>
            :host {
                display: block;
            }
        </style>

        <h3>{{element.name}}</h3>
        <h4>{{element.person.name}}</h4>
        <paper-button on-tap="_changeName">Change name!</paper-button>

    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'another-component',
            properties: {
                element: {
                    type: Object,
                    notify: true
                }
            },

            _changeName: function(){
                this.set('element.person', {"name": "bobby"});
                this.notifyPath('elements');
                this.notifyPath('element');
                this.notifyPath('element.person');

            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Child component is not changing the value of your parent component. As suggested by Jacob Miles, you need to fire an event to change the value. Then listen from the parent element where you can notify the changes of the whole elements array.

Here is the plnkr link : http://plnkr.co/edit/tuqKh4ANUTspa05GZ9mi?p=preview

Child component i.e. `another-component` is firing an event 'change-name':

`this.fire('change-name', {"newPersonName" : "bobby","index":this.i });`.

Parent component i.e. `example-component` is listening to that event and notifying the changes:

```
this.addEventListener('change-name', function (e) {
     this.elements[e.detail.index].person.name = e.detail.newPersonName;

     for(var i =0; i< this.elements.length; i++){
             this.notifyPath('elements.'+i+'.person.name'); 
     }

 });
```

To notify we need to use the exact path that changed, so I kept the `notifyPath` in loop (I did not find other way). I hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, I started playing with events yesterday night and I feel like this could be the way to go indeed. However what I don't like in your example is that the data is changing at the array level (you send the data up. I'd find it more clean to have the reference changed in the item directly, and be reflected upwards via a notify. Do you think it is possible?

Comment: Thanks for the plunkr, btw. The reason I think it should be possible to change data at element level is because we are using references to objects. So I'm expecting to somehow be able to influence items. The notifyPath can be done higher up, no issues

Comment: Alright, I modified your example to get it working as I want. You can see the result here : http://plnkr.co/edit/4OKtToJ3J2eBJrk50PXu?p=preview. Thanks for the help! BTW, it's worth noting you can also notify at person level directly

Comment: If you pass the whole array `elements` to child then you can reflect the changes in the parent component as well. But you are passing sub array and creating multiple child components that only have access to one object. That's why it is complicated. Anyway, I am glad that you liked the way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have your element that is actually doing the change fire an event saying that it changed the value. Then have the parent element listen for it and when it receives a changed event it can perform a `this.notifyPath('elements');` call.

In your calls to notifyPath you are passing in the object, but it should be string path not an object.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I have fixed the method to use strings. I had them as such in my original code, but forgot them when building this example. I have tried to notify elements as well, but without success.

Comment: Thanks Jacob. After reading your comments a few times yesterday night, I started getting what you meant. But it's only with Ofisora's mention of notifyPath that I could get it working